# CentOS 8, 'The font "FreeSerif" cannot be found.'

Tags: fonts, installing-fonts, centos

Fresh install of CentOS 8, using Sphinx (3.0.3), with latex-engine set to xelatex.

I've had a number of issues that have gone away with some work - search and install (cmap.sty for instance). I think I ended up doing `dnf install texlive-*` to try and get it to work.

Finally, I've hit a wall:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-english.ldf)kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid filename `[FreeSerif.otf]/OT', contains '['


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "FreeSerif" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

I successfully installed a bunch of freefonts `dnf install gnu-free-serif-fonts gnu-free-mono-fonts gnu-free-sans-fonts gnu-free-fonts-common`, I ran fc-cache and I can see the font in `fc-list | grep FreeSerif`:

```
/usr/share/fonts/gnu-free/FreeSerifBoldItalic.ttf: FreeSerif:style=Bold Italic,получерен курсивен,negreta cursiva,tučné kurzíva,fed kursiv,Fett-Kursiv,Negrita Cursiva,Lihavoitu Kursivoi,Gras Italique,Félkövér dőlt,Grassetto Corsivo,Vet Cursief,Halvfet Kursiv,Pogrubiona kursywa,Negrito Itálico,gros cursiv,Обычный Курсив,Tučná kurzíva,Fet Kursiv,ตัวเอียงหนา,Kalın İtalik,huruf tebal kursif,жирний курсив,Polkrepko Pežeče,treknais kursīvs,pusjuodis kursyvas,nghiêng đậm,Lodi etzana,धृष्ट-तिरछा
/usr/share/fonts/gnu-free/FreeSerifBold.ttf: FreeSerif:style=Bold,получерен,negreta,tučné,fed,Fett,Negrita,Lihavoitu,Gras,Félkövér,Grassetto,Vet,Halvfet,Pogrubiony,Negrito,gros,Обычный,Fet,ตัวหนา,Kalın,huruf tebal,жирний,Polkrepko,treknraksts,pusjuodis,ضخیم,đậm,Lodia,धृष्ट
/usr/share/fonts/gnu-free/FreeSerifItalic.ttf: FreeSerif:style=Italic,курсивен,cursiva,kurzíva,kursiv,Λειψίας,Kursivoitu,Italique,Dőlt,Corsivo,Cursief,kursywa,Itálico,cursiv,Курсив,ตัวเอียง,İtalik,kursif,Ležeče,kursīvs,kursivas,nghiêng,Etzana,तिरछा
/usr/share/fonts/gnu-free/FreeSerif.ttf: FreeSerif:style=Regular,нормален,normal,obyčejné,Mittel,µεσαία,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Gemiddeld,odmiana zwykła,Обычный,Normálne,ปกติ,menengah,прямій,Navadno,vidējs,normalusis,عادی,vừa,Arrunta,सामान्य
```

Seeing that the files are ttf and polyglossia calls for otf, I downloaded [the otf's](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/freefont/freefont-otf-20120503.tar.gz) from the [GNU website](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/freefont/), unpacked them, copied them into `/usr/share/fonts/gnu-free` and ran `fc-cache`. I'm still getting the same error - even though fc-list now finds them:

```
[root@server ~]# fc-list | grep FreeSerif.*otf
/usr/share/fonts/gnu-free/FreeSerifItalic.otf: FreeSerif:style=Italic,курсивен,cursiva,kurzíva,kursiv,Λειψίας,Kursivoitu,Italique,Dőlt,Corsivo,Cursief,kursywa,Itálico,cursiv,Курсив,ตัวเอียง,İtalik,kursif,Ležeče,kursīvs,kursivas,nghiêng,Etzana,तिरछा
/usr/share/fonts/gnu-free/FreeSerifBoldItalic.otf: FreeSerif:style=Bold Italic,получерен курсивен,negreta cursiva,tučné kurzíva,fed kursiv,Fett-Kursiv,Negrita Cursiva,Lihavoitu Kursivoi,Gras Italique,Félkövér dőlt,Grassetto Corsivo,Vet Cursief,Halvfet Kursiv,Pogrubiona kursywa,Negrito Itálico,gros cursiv,Обычный Курсив,Tučná kurzíva,Fet Kursiv,ตัวเอียงหนา,Kalın İtalik,huruf tebal kursif,жирний курсив,Polkrepko Pežeče,treknais kursīvs,pusjuodis kursyvas,nghiêng đậm,Lodi etzana,धृष्ट-तिरछा
/usr/share/fonts/gnu-free/FreeSerif.otf: FreeSerif:style=Regular,нормален,normal,obyčejné,Mittel,µεσαία,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Gemiddeld,odmiana zwykła,Обычный,Normálne,ปกติ,menengah,прямій,Navadno,vidējs,normalusis,عادی,vừa,Arrunta,सामान्य
/usr/share/fonts/gnu-free/FreeSerifBold.otf: FreeSerif:style=Bold,получерен,negreta,tučné,fed,Fett,Negrita,Lihavoitu,Gras,Félkövér,Grassetto,Vet,Halvfet,Pogrubiony,Negrito,gros,Обычный,Fet,ตัวหนา,Kalın,huruf tebal,жирний,Polkrepko,treknraksts,pusjuodis,ضخیم,đậm,Lodia,धृष्ट
```

Comment: I have managed to get it working by changing the latex engine back to the default in Sphinx. For some reason that wasn't working on CentOS 7, but on CentOS 8 it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've hit the same wall. Fortunately, [datakid](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/33238/datakid) showed the way in [the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546246/centos-8-the-font-freeserif-cannot-be-found#comment1379913_546246).

> changing the latex engine back to the default in Sphinx

To do so, I **removed** this line from the `conf.py`:

```
latex_engine = 'lualatex'
```

In my case, I still wanted to use LuaLaTeX to build the docs. This is what I did:

```
sphinx-build -b latex . ../pdf
cd ../pdf
make LATEXMKOPTS="-lualatex"
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx generates a `.tex` with the default font configuration specified as:

```
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}[
  Extension      = .otf,
  UprightFont    = *,
  ItalicFont     = *Italic,
  BoldFont       = *Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = *BoldItalic
]
\setsansfont{FreeSans}[
  Extension      = .otf,
  UprightFont    = *,
  ItalicFont     = *Oblique,
  BoldFont       = *Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = *BoldOblique,
]
\setmonofont{FreeMono}[
  Extension      = .otf,
  UprightFont    = *,
  ItalicFont     = *Oblique,
  BoldFont       = *Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = *BoldOblique,
]
```

This forces the font search via `kpathsea` (file name search), which is only configured to look into your TexLive installation path (TEXMF).  There are some solutions to the problem:

1. Edit out the `Extension...` arguments in the generated `.tex`, to restore fontconfig search.
2. Install the TexLive package offering the GNU FreeFont.
3. Symlink your /usr/share/fonts/* entries to your TEXMF installation so they are found.
4. Use lualatex which implement its own font search and handles this situation.

I could only find this thanks to hrnz on the #latex channel on libera.chat IRC, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way. I found my FreeSerif Font at directory :

/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/public/gnu-freefont/FreeSerif.ttf

So I double clicked it. My mac asked me whether I want to install this font. I clicked yes and it got installed. Then I recompiled the latex file and find it already works.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!